# How do I get TL15?

Tags: texlive

This question is extremely localised in time, but I decide to try asking it anyway: On [the TeX Live website](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html), it is claimed that TL15 has had an early release. However, if I go to [the download page](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) (which, according to the bottom of the page, was last updated in 2014), the Windows installer there is for TL14. **How do I get TL15?**

(I did report it to TUG already, but they have not replied yet; I am just wonderinng if there is a way to get TL15 for Windows already.)

Comment: Which mirror did you try? The distribution from the core DANTE server to the rest of the mirror network takes a day or so.

Comment: I just used to very first download link on the download page.

Comment: So is there another mirror that is likely to have it *now*? I guess I could experiment, but it appears there are several hundred CTAN mirrors.

Comment: If you re-word the question to something like 'how to obtain TL pre-releases', I don't think it will be too-localized.

Comment: @SeanAllred But that is the thing: It is *not* a pre-release, but the official release, according to the website.

Comment: *Current release: TeX Live 2015 is available over the Internet and on DVD. It was released on 11 June 2015, and ongoing updates are available.*

Comment: It was released today but it will take up to one day until all mirrors will have sync the tree.

Comment: @Sigur [Thanks Whatwolf](http://explosm.net/comics/2188/)

Comment: But I can not find the link for 2015. I guess that they are still updating the link on the web pages. http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

Comment: It is not fair to state they have released it if it is not really available. I want it now. `:-(`

Comment: If it was released today, your best chance is to get it from the DANTE server.

Comment: If a company says they are releasing a new product, it will take the trucks some time to ship it to the stores. Off-course, they could just wait till *all* stores are stocked up, which can take a week and defer the announcement that it is ready.

Comment: So I assume [this](ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/) is where I should look?

Comment: @Johannes_B, but TL15 is *not* a product released on trucks. `:-P`

Comment: @Gaussler I can understand your enthusiasm: you simply have to wait till tomorrow or some hours more, when all mirrors are updated. After all, if you order a book you have seen released, it takes some time until you have it in your hands. I voted for closing.

Comment: @egreg, I don't mind; my attention was directed to DANTE, where I found where I wanted. So I am satisfied. I might even vote for closing myself.

Comment: The primary Danish mirror (Dotsrc.org) is usually updated within 24 hours.

Comment: @Gaussler individuals are asked _not_ to use the main ctan hosts like dante: they should be reserved for feeding the mirrors.

Comment: @Gaussler If you were that desperate to use the updated code you should have been using the pre-test for TL'15 (and reporting any issues).

Comment: I got it on multiple ftps...ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images/  enjoy~

Comment: @texenthusiast I got it from some Chinese site anyway...

Comment: please use ctan mirror http://mir­ror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images to download texlive2015.iso files , this link would work after sometime once the root node feeds to its mirrors.

Comment: @Sigur My, how time flies…

Comment: @SeanAllred, sorry, I didn't follow your comment.  Maybe when you tried to read the post, TL15 was already available.

Comment: @Sigur No, not at all – I haven't updated yet :) I was merely commenting how quickly this latest release seems to have come up. In my own sense of time, I wasn't expecting it for quite a while – it feels like TL14 came out last month. Thus, *tempus fugit*.

Comment: Downloading one huge iso file using the torrent network also works very well: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html#torrent